# Google daydream - wrong initial camera orientation

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, daydream

I'm currently experiencing extremely strange behavior with Google Daydream on my Pixel 3 (Android 9 Pie). I simply load one of the Daydream demo scenes in Unity. A couple of months back, when I was first playing around with GVR everything worked fine.

However I just reinstalled the project and somehow the Daydream orientation is rotated by 90 degrees per default, which basically makes every application unusable if no additional correction is performed after initializing the application.

The following image should show the behavior I mean.
[image: Rotated Camera]

The Unity project is set up to only allow Landscape Left device orientation which is the default orientation for Daydream applications. Also auto-rotation is enabled in Android. Which should basically lead to a correct initialization of the application.

Might this be some internal Android issue? Or is there any global unity option that I might be missing here?

**EDIT:**
I couldn't figure out why the error occurred. A hard reset of the device was my final 'solution'.